# Month's name in FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Input: Month name (January / February / ... / December)

Output: Season (Winter / Spring / Summer / Autumn)

Winter: Dec - Feb

Spring: Mar - May

Summer: Jun - Aug

Autumn: Sept - Nov

I have tried:

```
Program Months;

var
  Month:String;

begin
  writeln('Insert month name:');
  readln(Month);

  if Month = 'March' or Month = 'April' or Month = 'May' then

    begin
    writeln(Month,' is Spring month');
    end

    ...
    etc   
    ...

end.
```

But this program is not working.

Comment: Not working is a terribly poor description of the actual problem. And this is the second question where you did this. You are risking downvotes with it. Next time: What was the error, on what line, what have you tried? Note also that this basically the same question as the last one, both missed parenthesis in if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator precedence - it's important. You need to write:

```
if (Month = 'March') or (Month = 'April') or (Month = 'May') then
```

This is because in Pascal, `or` has a higher priority than `=` so what is actually being evaluated is:

```
if ((Month = ('March' or Month)) = ('April' or Month)) = 'May' then
```

Which is obviously meaningless and will not compile (I might've made a mistake on the line above but it's the general idea). Please refer to [this link](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch12.html) to learn more about operator precedence in Pascal.